# Multiple Angular Apps using a common folder of modules

Tags: angular, module, reusability, code-reuse, modularity

What I am trying to achieve is reusable modules. However we have many applications that are different but all require some of the same basic building blocks. For example a module for graphs would be good for code reusability as all applications use the same graphs.

This being said I can only find ways to create a module inside an application. This is fine but does not work well in for our needs as it needs to be used in another application as well. What I would like is something like the following:

```
Projects:
  ProjectOne
  ProjectTwo
  ModuleGraphs
    Graph 1 component
    Graph 2 component
    graph service
    graph directive
    graph module
  ModuleCommon
    Table Component
      table html
      table css
    common module
```

I remember seeing a similar way in Angular 1.x but not sure how to go about it in Angular 2+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng generate library` command from the Angular CLI will create an Angular library project. This is available in Angular 6 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI 6.x adds the ability to create different types of projects in a workspace.

Hey, you can use NRWL workspace, In Nrwl WorkSpace you can create multiple applications, (app1, app2, app3, ...) and multiple libraries(lib1, lib2, lib3, ...) Each app and libs have a test environment which can be tested individually, Besides this, it adds lots of feature to existing CLI.

Nx is an extension for the Angular CLI implementing the monorepo-style development. It is also a collection of runtime libraries, linters, and code generators helping large teams build better with Angular.

to learn more visit https://nrwl.io/nx